# MATLAB sparse matrix solvers? memory errors

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix

In the context of a finite element problem, I have a 12800x12800 sparse matrix. I'm trying to solve the linear system just using MATLAB's `\` operator to solve and I get an out of memory error using mldivide. So I'm just wondering if there's a way to speed this up.

I mean, will something like LU factorization actually help here in terms of not getting the memory error anymore? I increased the heap size to 256 GB in preferences, which is the max I can get it to, and I still get the out of memory error.

Also, just a general question. I have 8GB of RAM on my laptop right now. Will upgrading to 16GB help at all? Or maybe something I can do to allocate more memory to MATLAB? I'm pretty unfamiliar with this stuff.

[image]

Comment: Once I peaked at Matlab's implementation of `mldivide`. It is a highly optimized code: taking into account the type and sparsity of the inputs. I do not think it is likely you'll be able to come up with something better unless you tailor it specifically to your specific configuration.

Comment: Can you post a plot of the sparsity pattern? (create with `spy(A)`)

Comment: Did you try LU factorization or other factorization methods? Also, if you are talking about Java heap memory, that won't help with the core MATLAB functions.

Comment: try to use the `amd` permutation: `perm=amd(A); A=A(perm,per);` This tends to limit the number of non-zero entries in your factor, that is - in the direct solver, which is being used by `mldivide`. Also, if your matrix is symmetric, use `L=chol(tril(A))` instead of `mldivide` - it uses only half of the space.

Comment: Is this problem still relevant? If so, have you looked at `help sparfun`? You can try a few of the functions mentioned under the `Linear Equations (iterative methods)` section.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://www.researchgate.net/post/How_to_increase_MATLABs_memory) and [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/resolving-out-of-memory-errors.html) you have some options to avoid out of memory problem in matlab:

- Increase operating system's virtual memory
- Give Higher priority to MATLAB process in task manager
- Use 64-bit version of MATLAB

Few months ago, I was working on integer programming in matlab. I faced "out of memory" problem, so I used sparse matrices and followed the mentioned tips, finally the problem is solved!

Answer (score 0):

Are you locked in to using mldivide? Sounds like the perfect situation for an iterative method - bicg, gmres etc?

Answer (score 0):

While backslash takes advantage of the sparsity of A, the qr method it uses produces full matrices that require (number_occupied_elements)^3 memory to be allocated. A few things you can try

1. If you're dividing sparse matrices with a few diagonals, you can try try to solve the system with forward/backwards substitution
2. Try breaking the problem into a smaller you break up the problem into a smaller
3. Run whos to see what elements are occupying your memory before you start the matrix division, can any of these be cleared beforehand?
4. Not applicable to your problem as you've stated it here, but if your system is defined (A has more rows than columns) than using the pseudo-inverse `(A.'*A)\(A.'*b)` produces a result using the smaller columns dimension

As for adding additional memory; Matlab32 uses 2^32 bytes of memory (4 Gb) so increasing the physical RAM on your computer won't help unless you're using the the 64 bit version.

Answer (score 0):

MATLAB `\` usually tries several methods to solve a problem. First, if it sees that if the structure of your matrix is  symmetric it tries a Cholesky factorization. After several steps if it can not find a suitable answer current version of Matlab uses UMFPACK [Suitsparse](http://faculty.cse.tamu.edu/davis/suitesparse.html) package.

UMFPack is a specific LU implemenation, and it is known for its speed and good usage of memory in practice. It also tries to reduce fill-in and keep matrix as sparse as possible. It is why MATLAB uses this code. 
(I am working on UMFPACK for my PhD under supervision of Dr Tim Davis, its creator)

Therefor, using another LU factorization won't help. It is an LU factorization already. 
One of the easiest way to solve your problem is testing your problem on another device with a better memory to see if it works.

I guess matlab do some garbage collection and waste some memory, so if you use the UMFPACK directly it might help you. You can either implement it in C/C++ or use MATLAB interface for it. Take a look at the SuitSparse package.

**Based on the structure of your matrix I think MATLAB tries to use Cholesky;** I don't know what is the strategy of MATLAB if Cholesky fails in memory management. Take into account that Cholesky is easier to manage in terms of memory.

There are other packages that might help you as well. CSparse is a lightweight package and it might help. There are other famouse packages that might be helpful; search for superLU.